# Why can't my entity with an @EmbeddedId use the LocalDateTime in it's corresponding @Embeddable Class?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I implemented an entity which uses `@EmbeddedId`. The `@Embeddable` - Class uses for one of the two comopiste key attributes the data type `LocalDateTime`. When I collect severeal properties via a controller I get the error that  `java.util.Date` is expected.
 I am using: `kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.2.71"` `Gradle: org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.10.Final` and a `MySQL - Server`

I managed to determine that the error occured when I implement the composite-key.

**Update:** The error occurs when I create a complete different entity (using LocalDateTime aswell). If I get rid of the composite key (and use just one property for @Id), there are no errors. But as soon as I implement the composite key, the error occurs. This is very confusing for me, since I do not know, why the composite key should affect an other entity

```
import java.io.Serializable
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId
import javax.persistence.Entity

@Entity(name = "entity")
class SensorHistory(@EmbeddedId val entityId: EntityId,
                    val value: Float) : Serializable {
}
```

```
import java.io.Serializable
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.Embeddable

@Embeddable
class EntityId(val timestamp: LocalDateTime,
               val sensor_id: Long) :
        Serializable {
}
```

Here is the part of a repository the controller is using:

```
@Query("SELECT COALESCE(SUM(value),0) FROM entity WHERE sensor_id = ?1 AND timestamp > ?2")
    fun countLitersSince(sensor_id: Long?, since: LocalDateTime): Float
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2000-01-01T12:00:01] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2000-01-01T12:00:01] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.countLitersSince(Unknown Source)
    at de.iteratec.sodadispenser.controller.SodaDispenserController.getAllSodaDispensers(SodaDispenserController.kt:39)
    at de.iteratec.sodadispenser.tests.controller.SodaDispenserControllerTest.check(SodaDispenserControllerTest.kt:121)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2000-01-01T12:00:01] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:403)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.lambda$setParameter$5(QueryParameterSetter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$ErrorHandling$1.execute(QueryParameterSetter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.lambda$bind$0(ParameterBinder.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: I would say that in your db you want to have a date type.

Comment: An other entity uses LocalDateTime and I got no problems.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this part of the code? In your error, I'm seeing a reference to `java.util.Date` you're not using. I'm also seeing a reference to `countLitersSince` within your stack trace. Can you show that code?

Comment: @g00glen00b I added it to the original post

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Shouldn't you change your query into `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(value),0) FROM entity WHERE entity.entityId.sensor_id = ?1 AND entity.entityId.timestamp > ?2`?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this. I would say since this is only in my application and `EntityId` is an embedded class my database would stay the same. I still only have the `entity` table in my database and there is no `entityId` table in it @g00glen00b

Comment: True, but if you're using Spring Data JPA, the `@Query` annotation requires you to use JPQL, not SQL. This means that the query should follow your entity structure in stead of your table structure. If you don't want this, you can add [`nativeQuery = true`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#nativeQuery--). What surprises me is that the error doesn't make this really clear though, so I'm not certain if this will fix the issue.

Comment: what is the naming convention here? My `EntityId` class does not have the `@Entity(name = "some_name")` annotation.
Further I noticed:
The error occurs when I create a complete different entity (using LocalDateTime aswell). If I get rid of the composite key (and use just one property for @Id), there are no errors. But as soon as I implement the composite key, the error occurs.
This is very confusing for me, since I do not know, why the composite key should affect an other entity. @g00glen00b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace within your question indicates that the error is within your repository call `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.countLitersSince`. The reason is that the query isn't valid, as `timestamp` nor `sensor_id` exist that way.

If you're using Spring Data JPA, the default query language is JPQL, which stands for JPA Query Language. This means that queries should follow your entity declaration:

- While your entity name normally is `SensorHistory`, you renamed it, and should thus query from `entity` like you did.
- Additionally, it uses a more object-oriented approach. Since `value` is part of `entity`, it should become `entity.value`.
- The same should happen to `sensor_id` and `timestamp`. Both fields are part of `entity.entityId` and should be replaced as well.

```
@Query("select coalesce(sum(entity.value), 0) from entity where entity.entityId.sensor_id = ?1 and entity.entityId.timestamp > ?2")
fun countLitersSince(sensor_id: Long?, since: LocalDateTime): Float
```

Alternatively, if you want to use plain SQL, you can set [`nativeQuery`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#nativeQuery--) to `true`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(value),0) FROM entity WHERE sensor_id = ?1 AND timestamp > ?2", nativeQuery = true) // Add nativeQuery
fun countLitersSince(sensor_id: Long?, since: LocalDateTime): Float
```

I'm not certain why the error isn't being more clear on this. Normally it should throw an exception telling you that it doesn't know what to do with "entity", "timestamp" or "sensor_id", but somehow it manages to find an entity called `entity` with a `timestamp` field of type `java.util.Date`.

---

From the comments it appears you named your entity `StatusHistory` and your table is named `status_history`. If you want to use JPQL, you could change your entities to look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sensor_history")
class SensorHistory(@EmbeddedId val id: SensorHistoryId,
                    val value: Float) : Serializable {
}

@Embeddable
class SensorHistoryId(val timestamp: LocalDateTime,
                      @Column(name = "sensor_id") val sensorId: Long) : Serializable {
}
```

And then you should be able to use a query like this one:

```
@Query("select coalesce(sum(sh.value), 0) from SensorHistory sh where sh.id.sensorId = ?1 and sh.id.timestamp > ?2")
fun countLitersSince(sensorId: Long?, since: LocalDateTime): Float
```

Using the `@Table` and `@Column` annotations you can properly use alternative names within your Kotlin classes.

Comment: Thank you sir! The approach with the `nativeQuery = true` worked for me. Although I don't no how to apply the other approach. My real entities are: SensorHistory(instead of Entity) /sensor_history (in the database) and SensorHistoryId (instead of EntityId). How should the query look?

Comment: I've added an example to the bottom of my answer.